# Why can't I whitelist sysfs paths when ProtectKernelTunables=yes

Tags: systemd

The `systemd` documentation is a little vague about whether this works
From the [`ProtectKernelTunables` section](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectKernelTunables=):

> For this setting the same restrictions regarding mount propagation and privileges apply as for ReadOnlyPaths= and related calls, see above.

This makes me think I can set `ProtectKernelTunables=yes` and then add `ReadWritePaths=/sys/class/leds`. However when I try it I see the following in the logs:

```
Dec 03 03:33:55 radio00000 systemd[25829]: /run/systemd/unit-root/sys is duplicate.
Dec 03 03:33:55 radio00000 systemd[25829]: /run/systemd/unit-root/sys is duplicate.
...
Dec 03 03:33:55 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Successfully mounted /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/sys to /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/sys
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Applying namespace mount on /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Successfully mounted /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds to /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Not remounting /run/systemd/unit-root/sys, because blacklisted by /run/systemd/unit-root/sys, called for /run/systemd/unit-root
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Not remounting /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/sys, because blacklisted by /run/systemd/unit-root/proc, called for /run/systemd/unit-root
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Not remounting /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds, because blacklisted by /run/systemd/unit-root/sys, called for /run/systemd/unit-root
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Not remounting /run/systemd/unit-root/sys, because blacklisted by /run/systemd/unit-root/sys, called for /run/systemd/unit-root
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Not remounting /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds, because blacklisted by /run/systemd/unit-root/sys, called for /run/systemd/unit-root
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Remounted /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/sys read-only.
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Not remounting /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds, because blacklisted by /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds, called for /run/systemd/unit-root/sys
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Remounted /run/systemd/unit-root/sys read-only.
...
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 systemd[25829]: Not remounting /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds, because blacklisted by /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/class/leds, called for /run/systemd/unit-root/sys
...
```

And then from my daemon:

```
Dec 03 03:33:56 radio00000 lightsd[25829]: Cannot open /sys/class/leds/led-msg/brightness: Read-only file system
```

In fact, if I try

```
ReadOnlyPaths=/sys
ReadWritePaths=/sys/class/leds
```

I have the same problem. It seems like these should work. Is this a known bug in systemd239, am I doing something that's not possible, or did I miss something important?

I'm using system 239, Linux 4.19